# Why am I getting undefined entries in the following javascript code

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

So below is my javascript code

```js
const rData = [[{"prop11": 10}, {"prop2": 12}]];
       const tData = [];
       const tddData = [];
       for(const item of rData[0]){
         tData.push(Object.keys(item).toString());
         console.log('trData...', tData);
         tData.map(y => {
           tddData.push(item[y]);
           console.log('tdDta....', tddData);
         });
       }
```

Following is the output of the console.logs

```
trData... Array [ "prop11" ] 
tdDta.... Array [ 10 ] 
trData... Array [ "prop11", "prop2" ] 
tdDta.... Array [ 10, undefined ] 
tdDta.... Array [ 10, undefined, 12 ]
```

I can't seem to understand where those undefined values are coming from. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the second iteration of the `for` loop, `item` is `{"prop2": 12}` and `tData` is `["prop11", "prop2"]`. When you call `tData.map()`, you do:

```
tddData.push(item["prop11"]);
tddData.push(item["prop2"]);
```

Since there is no `item["prop11"]`, you get `undefined` for that one.

`tData` contains the keys from all the previous objects in the array, so you'll get `undefined` whenever a later object doesn't have those previous keys.

Also, if any of the object has multiple properties, `Object.keys(item).toString()` will be a comma-separated list of keys. For instance, if you have

```
{"key1": 1, "key2": 3}
```

you'll push `"key1,key2"` onto `tdData`. When you try to use this in `item[y]`, you'll get `undefined`.

Comment: I just wanted to know the cause. Wanted to get rid of those undefined from the final array of tddData, could have used another method and done it but wanted to know the root cause to avoid it in the first place. You did that. Thanks.